# Set two variables from command output

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach

I'm basically performing a specific search in Exchange and I want to use the `$_.Name` & `$_.Alias` as variables.

I'm easily able to use the following to set one of the variables:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | where {$_.DisplayName -match "user"} | foreach {$_.Alias} -OutVariable alias
```

On the same line, how can I set a second variable using the `$_.Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that only one record is returned, you can assign `$Alias` and `$Name` in one line like this:

```
$Alias, $Name = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    where {$_.DisplayName -match "user"} | 
    foreach {$_.Alias; $_.Name}
```

Comment: foreach {$_.Alias; $_.Name} - what does this do?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Just puts both properties into the pipeline which I then use to assign both variables

Comment: @4c74356b41 hm, not sure but if it helps you to imagine what im doing here I guess the comparison is fine. You can test the above using: `$myid, $myname = ps | select -first 1 | % { $_.Id; $_.Name }`

Comment: it puts 1 value in the first var and everything else into the second

Comment: @MartinBrandl Thank you!!  That is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  Works perfectly.